# Interface with a method that requires parameter of implementation type in signature

Tags: java, interface

Here is an example to clarify what I'm meaning: Let's say I have two classes:

```
class A {
    boolean isEqual(A instance);
}
```

and

```
class B {
    boolean isEqual(B instance);
}
```

Is there a possibility in Java to define an interface such as

```
interface I {
    // signature for isEqual(...) here
}
```

so that the isEqual method in all implementations takes the parameter of the implementation type? Like

```
class C implements I {
    boolean isEqual(C instance);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `T extends Object`  ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```
interface Equatable<T> {
    public boolean isEqual(T instance);
}

class C implements Equatable<C> {
    boolean isEqual(C instance);
}
```

This is similar to the standard [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for and it did not even require any special knowledge! nice and elegant. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was also able to do something similar in C#

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility in Java to define an interface such as ...

Yes, In  generic form:

```
public interface I<T> {
    public boolean isEqual(T instance);
}

public class C  implements I<C> {

    @Override
    public boolean isEqual(C instance) {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

Or for example if class `A`, `B` and `C` inherit some super class, lets say `DD`.

So you can write:

```
interface I {
   boolean isEqual(<? extends DD> instance);
}
```

Comment: This is the same as the answer I accepted, but thanks anyway!